# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [ExpressionEngine® Answers](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Suggested method to watermark images on a case-by-case basis? (Matrix+CE Image or Channel Image)](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9327/suggested-method-to-watermark-images-on-a-case-by-case-basis-matrixce-image-o)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Require account activation with Cartthrob and Profile:edit issue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/require-account-activation-with-cartthrob-and-profileedit-issue)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Playa php errors after upgrade to 4.4.1](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/playa-php-errors-after-upgrade-to-4-4-1)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Can I do {exp:channel:entries channel="*wildcardsearch*"}?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/can-i-do-expchannelentries-channel-wildcardsearch)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [selecting the last 2 rows of a matrix](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/selecting-the-last-2-rows-of-a-matrix)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [EE Addon Module - How to store a value in a EE session?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9700/ee-addon-module-how-to-store-a-value-in-a-ee-session)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Produce a list of entries that have no relationship parents](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10035/produce-a-list-of-entries-that-have-no-relationship-parents)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why are PHP and Stash variables not set as expected within EE conditionals?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9376/why-are-php-and-stash-variables-not-set-as-expected-within-ee-conditionals)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Saving JSON to member field?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/saving-json-to-member-field)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [ExpressionEngine API - Adding a category](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/expression-engine-api-adding-a-category)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)